# Comparison of Integer with nil failed in bubble sort algorithm

Tags: ruby, comparison, argument-error

I am creating a bubble sort algorithm. Why do I get the error message comparison of Integer with nil failed (ArgumentError)?

```
def bubble_sort(arr)

  arr.each_with_index do |i, j|    
    print arr[j]
    print arr[j+1]

    if arr[j] > arr[j+1]
      print "swap"
    end 
  end

  print arr

end

bubble_sort([4,3,78,2,0,2])
```

Comment: When you get to the last element of `arr`, `j = arr.size-1` and `i = arr[j]`. Then you compare `arr[j]` with `arr[j+1]`. The latter is therefore equal to `nil`, so you are comparing an integer with `nil`. (Presumable, `arr` contains integers.)

Comment: Even when you fix your problem your algorithm won't work because you are not actually swapping elements of `arr`. With `puts "swap"` you're just saying you are. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you ask the script to read the `J+1` index when the last index could be `j`. Or in other words you are asking to access a nil value in array. You have to ensure that you are not try to access `n+1` element in your array.
Simply just check and break from loop if you reach the last element:

```
break if arr.size-1 == j #j is the last index now
```

Second, you are not doing anything in your code but printing. You can do something

```
temp = arr[j]
arr[j] = arr[j+1]
arr[j+1] = temp
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works. The script is more of en exercise. Now i can actually do something with it :-)

Comment: Recall that with *parallel assignment* (aka *multiple assignment*) you don't need the  variable (`temp`). Just `arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]`. It's not accurate to say, "you are asking to access a `nil` value in array". After all, arrays may contain `nil` elements. I believe you mean that the OP is trying to index an element with an index that is greater than the index of the last element of the array (`arr.size-1`), so `nil` is returned. Yes, a bit wordy, but such is life. Lastly, I don't think you would `break` from the loop; you would simply never have an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. Regarding your second point, you are talking about something like this? `arr.each_with_index do |element, index|; if arr.size-1 != index; arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index+1], arr[index]; end; end`

Answer (score 0):

Array element with index `j+1` cannot be found as you iterate over the array with `.each_with_index`. `j+1` returns `nil` and then you try to compare it with `arr[j]` which causes Argument error.

`.each_with_index` is not useful here as you use only indexes. And you need to run check again if unsorted values found.

My suggestion is to use a loop from  0 to the last possible index value. Something like this:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  index = 0

  while index < arr.size - 1 do
    if arr[index] > arr[index+1]
      arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index+1], arr[index]
      index = 0
    else
      index += 1
    end
  end

  print arr
end

bubble_sort([4,3,78,2,0,2]) # => [0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 78]
```